# Select first matching string value in list from SQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I'd like to query **Table** and return the most granular frequency in the table for a given row. Sample table and desired result are below. I've tried a few iterations of the query but haven't cracked it yet.

By "most granular frequency" I mean that I'd like to return the first match for any row in this set ['hourly', 'daily', 'weekly', 'monthly'] as a new column called `min_frequency`

**Table**

```
----------------------------------
id     | name          | frequency
----------------------------------
----------------------------------
1      | apples        | hourly
----------------------------------
2      | apples        | daily
----------------------------------
3      | oranges       | weekly
----------------------------------
4      | oranges       | monthly
----------------------------------
```

**Desired result:**

---

```
name          | min_frequency
----------------------------------
----------------------------------
apples        | hourly
----------------------------------
oranges       | weekly
----------------------------------
```

**Current attempt:**

```
SELECT name, (
  CASE 
   WHEN frequency='hourly' then frequency
   WHEN frequency='daily' then frequency
   WHEN frequency='weekly' then frequency
   WHEN frequency='yearly' then frequency
  END
) as min_frequency from Table
GROUP BY name, min_frequency
```

Comment: Rows have no order unless you add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `distinct on` with conditional sorting logic:

```
select distinct on (name) *
from mytable
order by 
    name, 
    case frequency
        when 'hourly'  then 1
        when 'daily'   then 2
        when 'weekly'  then 3
        when 'monthly' then 4
    end
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I hadn't come across `distinct on` until now and it's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Although you can use a giant `case` expression, arrays are convenient for this:

```
select distinct on (name) t.*
from t
order by name,
         array_position(array['hourly', 'daily', 'weekly', 'monthly'], frequency)
```

Note if you have frequencies other than those listed, this may not work as expected.

Comment: Misprint. `array_position(array['hourly', 'daily', 'weekly', 'monthly', 'yearly'], frequency)`

Comment: Thank you for this, I hadn't come across `distinct on` until now and it's exactly what I was looking for. Upvoted